# Saved MMC console not saving remote computer snap-ins

Tags: windows

Has anyone seen this problem?

From my domain controller logged in as a domain admin, create a MMC.

Add a snap-in for Windows Server Backup for a remote computer in the same domain.
Add a snap-in for Windows Server Backup for another remote computer in the same domain.

Save the MMC on the desktop and then close the opened MMC.

Double-click on the saved MMC on the desktop.

It shows two snap-ins for Windows Server Backup - but for the local computer.

I'm logged in as a domain admin, I even tried right-clicking the MMC and chose Run-As-Administrator

Any ideas on why it's not saving the remote computers?

Comment: What versions are you working with?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the thread here, this is by design](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/windowsbackup/thread/0e15d449-4931-4a45-8763-889f43fb3a8e).

I had better luck by just adding the Server Manager snap-in instead. This still forces a few more clicks out of you, but it's better than having to log into each server manually.

Comment: I like how that thread references this as a workaround.